# Find minimal set of edges in k-partite graph that every k-clique has an edge from this set.

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

There is given $k$-partite graph $G$, where independent sets have following cardinalities: $n_{1},n_{2},...,n_{k}$
We say that $k$-clique is marked if has at least one edge from given set of edges $A$.

> Find $A$, such every $k$-clique in $G$ is marked.

Writing "find" i mean : find algorithm to construct that set, find the number $|A|$, find other properties such as the highest degree of some vertex.

I tried to apply Turan graphs for $k-1$ partite graph, then use it for every selected subset of independent sets. But it does not work. For example for $k=4$; $n_{1}=n_{2}=n_{3}=n_{4}=2$.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

HINT (in case this is homework)

The given graph $G$ is clearly inspired by Turan, but you don't need the theorem, nor another Turan graph (e.g. with $k-1$ parts).  Instead, inspired by Turan's *reasoning*, what can you say about:

- Is there any $(k+1)$-clique in $G$?
- There are $k$-cliques in $G$.  Can you characterize them in some way?
- Finally, if $A$ is such that every $k$-clique is marked, that also means if all edges in $A$ are *removed*, then there will be no more $k$-cliques.  Perhaps this is an easier way to visualize the problem: What edges would you remove from $G$  s.t. there are no more $k$-cliques?

Does this help?  Or do you need more hint?

Comment: 1.There are no k+1-clique this is because of pigeonhole principle. 2. There are k-clique and every vertex is from different independent set. 3. I have no idea which edges schould be removed.

Comment: Re: #3: a $k$-clique must have one vertex from each set.  So the first thing that comes to mind is removing an entire set, or in the context of edges, removing all the edges associated with one set.  This is clearly sufficient.  However, you can remove fewer edges than that.  E.g. if you remove all edges between two given sets, then even though you can assemble $k$ nodes from $k$ parts, the subgraph will be a $k$-clique MINUS that one edge.  This is the minimum $|A|$ solution I can think of, but I am not sure that is truly the minimum.